# Perl MIME::Lite is breaking up HTML body

Tags: perl, email-attachments

Back around 2004 I wrote a Perl emailer with MIME::Lite which has been working ever since then. Only now is the client trying to send HTML with it. The following code (trimmed down to the significant parts) properly sets all values. The HTML body is attached as text/html. Prior to the attachment the data clearly has no CR (CRLF, or LF). But after attaching it the HTML *does* have an embedded CR. This seems to be added after 1000 characters.

Unfortunately it's landing in the middle of a tag, thus breaking the tag which is rendering as a tag in the recipients email, rather than rendering entirely as formatted text: `<BR>` is displays as `< BR>`. And it's not breaking on the specific tag. I can change the tags and it always breaks around the same character position. I've read through the MIME::Lite code (with my very rusty Perl skills), but I don't see where it would be doing this split operation.

```
use MIME::Lite; # v3.030

my $bodyWithNoCR = "<html>" . ("x" x 1020) . "</html>";

my $mime_msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From => 'x@x.com',
    To   => 'x@x.com',
    Subject => 'Subject',
    Type    =>'multipart/mixed')
or die "$!\n";

$mime_msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $bodyWithNoCR)
or die "$!\n";

my $bodyWithCR = $mime_msg->as_string;
```

It's not just `as_string` which shows this, the Net::SMTP dump shows the HTML split across lines, and this is reflected in the recipient's email client.

I know MIME::Lite is considered buggy. But my question is if this specific issue is recognized (preferably with a reference to a tracker ID). A response of "yes, I've seen that" is helpful but (respectfully) isn't enough to confirm for a fact that this is a known issue in old code. If I can find a tracker item for this issue then I'll know if I can look for a patch or if I need to suggest to the user that this specific code can't be used for this specific purpose.

Can anyone suggest alternative code for the `attach()` that might cause it to avoid whatever it is that's breaking up the block?

As to using other tools (an expected response), I rewrote this all with PHPMailer many years later for other clients, but the API is different and it would be a hassle for the client to retool to use that. I could also replace MIME::Lite with something else (as recommended by the maintainers) but on the old Linux box a requirement for a dependency chain might preclude loading anything more current. That said, alternative approaches with MIME::Lite are welcome.

Without a better solution at this time, the only workaround being considered (but not liked at all) is to build the HTML with embedded spaces from columns 980-1020, 1980-2020, etc, so that even if a CR is embedded, the whitespace isn't visible in the recipient's mail client. (Yeah, yuck!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#L639) might have something to do with what's going on:

```
#------------------------------
#
# encode_8bit STRING
#
# Encode the given string using 8BIT.
# This breaks long lines into shorter ones.

sub encode_8bit {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s/^(.{990})/$1\n/mg;
    $str;
}
```

Comment: UGH! It should be quoted printable for strings longer than 1000 characters. I think this is it! Checking the code. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the code from 2004 was updated in 2006 but the client never got that version which does enforce quoted-printable for HTML. This question has been answered!

Answer (score 2):

SMTP servers have line length restrictions which can allow as few as 1000 octets. As such, MIME::Lite gives the following instructions for selecting the content transfer encoding:

```
Use encoding:     | If your message contains:
------------------------------------------------------------
7bit              | Only 7-bit text, all lines <1000 characters
8bit              | 8-bit text, all lines <1000 characters
quoted-printable  | 8-bit text or long lines (more reliable than "8bit")
base64            | Largely non-textual data: a GIF, a tar file, etc.
```

The heuristics defaulted to using 8bit, so MIME::Lite was adding line breaks to do the best it could with an unsuitable input. The solution is to tell MIIME::Lite to use the `quoted-printable` (or `base64`) encoding.

```
$mime_msg->attach(
    Type     => 'text/html',
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
    Data     => $bodyWithNoCR)
or die "$!\n";
```

---

*[In the comments the OP cleared up that they meant "line break" when they said "CR". However, the OP still mentions CR, so I'm leaving this passage here.]*

As for the Carriage Returns, I wasn't getting any even before adding `Encoding => 'quoted-printable'`. I suspect that your `$bodyWithCR` had no Carriage Returns, and that the bug was in your means of inspecting it. Specifically, I think you printed `$bodyWithCR` to a handle without doing `binmode` on it first.

Comment: This is all correct, I've also found that documentation, confirmed the issue, and accepted the first answer. But your edits to my code and your resulting response lost a significant point, that the source data did not have a CR. So perhaps you can edit your response here to reflect this for posterity. But this has been answered and we can wrap it up. Thanks.

Comment: If the source data has no CR, why do you keep editing a CR into my source data? That changes the nature of the report.

Comment: Fair enough but the source had neither CR nor LF. The SMTP log and recipient email showed a "line break". I didn't look to see the ASCII value of the character that was inserted. You are correct that CR wasn't being inserted, it was an LF, but the LF was not in the source. I'm hoping we can leave this as-is rather than going back with major edits to change (my assumption of) CR to LF or a more generic EOL. Thanks.